# Submit Button on Modal will not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, modal-dialog

The submit button on the modal has a class named "btn.btn-success" and thus I am trying to have the button collect the value that I plug into the modal and eventually append them to the bottom of a post. my solution for this part looks like this

```
    $(".btn.btn-success").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var title = $('#titlereply').val();
        var email = $('#emailreply').val();
        var comment = $('#commentreply').val();
        var replyFormat = '<div class="comment-content media-body clearfix">'
                    + '<h3 class="media-heading">' + title + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By <a href="#">' + email
                    + '</a> | Today, 12:31</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>'
                    + comment + ' <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray more reply" id="replyComment2">Reply</a></div>';

        $(sabio.page.replyRef).closest('.comment-content').append(replyFormat);
    });
```

I've tried placing alerts and breaks while running the solution and for some reason it will not run past the on click part where it says e.preventDefault; so there must be an issue there but I cannot find it. I am absolutely sure that the class "btn.btn-success" is referring to the modal's submit button. But just in case it may help this is the modal's script

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Submit Reply" class="btn.btn-success"
                           data-formid="#comment-form-reply">

Comment: I wouldn't use the class. You could have other buttons. Assign the button and id and use that. Also, in this case the button class needs to be class="btn btn-success". In your JQuery, it needs to be $(".btn-success").on... that is enough. Ideally, if you change you button to "<input type ="button" id="submitForm" class="btn btn-success" /> then use $('#submitForm').on('click', function().....

Comment: If I didn't make it clear. You don't need a . in the button class name. Only the JQuery selector needs a .

Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Here is the JS object:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )
{
    $.buttonManager = {
        manage: function(element, appendist) {
            $(element).on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $('#titlereply').val();
            var email = $('#emailreply').val();
            var comment = $('#commentreply').val();
            var replyFormat = '<div class="comment-content media-body clearfix">' + '<h3 class="media-heading">' + title + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By <a href="#">' + email + '</a> | Today, 12:31</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>' + comment + ' <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray more reply" id="replyComment2">Reply</a></div>';
            $(appendist).find('.comment-content').append(replyFormat);
        });
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML for the form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test Form
        </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/index.html">
            <input type="text" id="titlereply" placeholder="Title" />
            <input type="text" id="emailreply" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="text" id="commentreply" placeholder="Comment" />
            <button class="btn" id="myButton">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div id="result">
            <div class="comment-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
           $.buttonManager.manage('.btn', '#result'); 
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Note how all you need to do to get the button to behave the way you want is:

```
$.buttonManager.manage('.btn', '#result');
```

Where '.btn' is the element identifying the button and '#result' is the element where it looks for comment-content to append.

Working example on: http://sb.meezaan.net/so/33571486/

OLD ANSWER:
For the button, use:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit Reply" class="btn btn-success" data-formid="#comment-form-reply">
```

For JQuery, use:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#titlereply').val();
    var email = $('#emailreply').val();
    var comment = $('#commentreply').val();
    var replyFormat = '<div class="comment-content media-body clearfix">'
                + '<h3 class="media-heading">' + title + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By <a href="#">' + email
                + '</a> | Today, 12:31</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>'
                + comment + ' <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray more reply" id="replyComment2">Reply</a></div>';

    $(sabio.page.replyRef).closest('.comment-content').append(replyFormat);
});
```

Comment: I know I could try to target it by the ID but I have several reply buttons and if I target them it would get complicated in the long run. On top of that I actually did try to do it in that route and the submit button was still unresponsive.

Comment: You need  a jquery object  / plugin. I'll post an example on Monday. Then you can instantiate on any button by class or Id on any page without any conflicts.

Comment: Can you share your page markup, please. What is $(sabio.page.replyRef)? Are these classes? That is an incorrect jQuery reference. Also, I'm posting the JS object shortly, but referencing IDs inside a class button click - bad idea. Because an ID can only exist on the page once - a class, many times.

Comment: Appreciate the help I was able to find the solution. Thanks for the help.